# Unable to filter in python using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Here is the python code

```
languages = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
print filter(lambda x: x == "Python",languages)
```

The output is:

```
[u'Python']
```

Where does the `u` come from and how to avoid it.

Required output:

```
['Python']
```

***Update::***

I was trying this on code academy.I guess dere was a bug in their software.

Comment: It certainly doesn't come from anything you've shown here. Your example code yields `['Python']`.

Comment: The `u` just means the output is a unicode string.  Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Note that where using `filter()` with `lambda`, you are better off with a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw). E.g: `[x for x in languages if x == "Python"]`.

Comment: Could you specify in you are using Python 2.x or Python 3.x. The way strings are handled has changed between Python 2.x and Python 3.x so this information might help.

Comment: @Xion345 He's using 2.x, 3.x doesn't do the `u''` thing on unicode strings (it does `b''` on byte strings instead). Not to mention the use of `print` as a statement.

Comment: The issue is discussed here as well: http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/510969084f0fdcaa0d00115c

Answer (score 1):

Your input contains `unicode` text, not `str` text. The `u''` indicates a `unicode` literal.

This is probably normal, and depends entirely on where you got your `languages` list *from*. Things are otherwise *working*.

The CodeAcademy exercise you link to is actually *broken*. It shows you Python `str` input and but it's output uses `unicode`. You need to report that as a bug.

You can work around that bug by mapping everything to a `str`:

```
print filter(lambda x: x=='Python', map(str, languages))
```

or by mapping the *output* of `filter` to `str()`:

```
print map(str, filter(lambda x: x=='Python', languages))
```

which works for **this case** because the input only uses ASCII characters. **Normally** you'd encode `unicode` to `str` explicitly by specifying an encoding instead, see the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: can i print the output as ['Python']

Comment: @iBlue Why do you want to do that? If you want to display a list of items, then do something like `", ".join()` to get a textual representation as you want it, don't use Python's representation. If you want the representation as Python sees it, this is what is appropriate. When you use the unicode strings from the list, they will function normally, it's only their representation which is different.

Comment: @iBlue: Why do you *need* to?

Comment: Well i'm trying to solve a problem from here http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-KAgt5/3#!/exercises/1

Comment: @iBlue They have a bug in their software - I suggest you contact them. You have done it correctly, just progress on.

Comment: The u is not actually part of the string. Every time you print it in some way it will not show, instead the format will just be in unicode. Python 3 uses unicode strings as standard strings and doesn't show the u at all, although technically it's still there. Basically, regard it as decoration and ignore it.

Comment: @iBlue: That's a *bug* then in that exercise. That is not how the normal python interpreter would respond.

Comment: @iBlue: FYI, the codecademy courses are often buggy in that they're too picky with the code.  Look at the corresponding `Q&A Forum` for that exercise in the codecademy site, and you will often see that others had a similar problem (sometimes it's as simple as indentation, e.g.)

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward conversion is made with:

```
languages = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
flt = filter(lambda x: x == "Python",languages)
print [str(X) for X in flt]
```

Output

```
['Python']
```

Yes, the simple `str()` is doing conversion.

Comment: Again, this doesn't mention the potential issues with doing this conversion, and is completely unnecessary 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score -1):

`u` stands for unicode, you can convert it to a normal string with `str(filter(...))`

Comment: -1, this is a bad idea, Unicode text should be fine (in fact, better), 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @Lattyware he asked... i didn't say it was good or bad, it's up to him to decide whether he wants it

Comment: You say 'you can remove it' which makes it seem like something simple and doesn't explain the downsides to doing it. Not to mention, the asker doesn't always know what they want.

Comment: This outputs `"[u'Python']"` because `filter()` returns a list.